# How to set a unique DNS entry in Windows organizational domain?

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, domain

I wasn't sure what to write in the title since I'm not familiar with the technical terms regarding DNS.

I have an IIS web server that is part of a domain in my organization, which I'll refer to as "company.abc". 
Most web servers in the organization's domain use standard hostnames, and the DC servers DNS is configured to pair each IP address with said IP's hostname, as such: hostname.company.abc

I want to configure the DNS servers in the organization to pair my server's IP address to the name "yahoo.xyz" without having to add a whole new lookup zone for "xyz" .

What would be the best way to do this without having to make any "big" changes to the current DNS configuration. 
A friend mentioned "root hints", but I'm unsure what exactly would need to be configured.

Comment: Well.. are the clients configured with a DNS search suffix?

Comment: Some are, but not all. And out of those that are, none are configured with "xyz" as a search suffix. What I'm in the process of doing, is configuring my web server as a DNS server that will have the "xyz" zone configured, with only one host name under it, "yahoo". After reading up on Root Hints, I've added my web+DNS server to the list of Root Hints on the organization's main DNS server. Now that everything is set, I still can't resolve "yahoo.xyz",  I've checked firewall settings and everything else Google had to offer.

Comment: Root hints definitely aren't what you want to use for that.  Sounds like it's Microsoft DNS as the organization's main DNS, is that correct?

Comment: If you mean a Microsoft domain environment, then yes. If you mean original Microsoft files, then no. All DNS records are created and maintained by my company, the network isn't connected to the internet.

Comment: What I mean is whether the DNS software running the company DNS is Microsoft DNS on your domain controllers, or something else like BIND.

Comment: It's Microsoft DNS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few different ways you can do this:

- Just create a new forward lookup zone on the Microsoft DNS instead of putting a second DNS service on your web server.  This is the right way to do what you're trying to do, and is a whole lot less disruptive of a change to your company's DNS servers than the change to the root hints (which you should never need to do).
- If you need to control the zone's contents on your web server, you can create a stub zone instead of an authoritative zone, pointing to the web server as a delegation.
- If you have some reason that you're not able to create a forward lookup zone, then you can set up a conditional forwarder for the zone.

Comment: Wouldn't a delegation give authority only for a subdomain inside the organization? The domain I would like to manage is under a completely new TLD zone ("xyz" instead of "abc").

Comment: @John No - the BIND server answers as authoritative, a stub zone will cause the Windows DNS servers to sent queries to it.